# Coupling of python interpreter used by my project and by pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

Installing my requirements fails:

```
» pipenv --python 3.6.4 install
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/bin/python3.6m to create virtualenv…
⠋Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/bin/python3.6m
Using base prefix '/home/myuser/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4'
New python executable in /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/svc-J_VF07t3/bin/python3.6m
Also creating executable in /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/svc-J_VF07t3/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /home/myuser/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location: /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/svc-J_VF07t3
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
n2.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 11, in <module>
    import pipenv.utils
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/../pipenv/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .cli import cli
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/../pipenv/cli.py", line 10, in <module>
    import delegator
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/delegator.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pexpect.popen_spawn import PopenSpawn
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pexpect/popen_spawn.py", line 14, in <module>
    from Queue import Queue, Empty  # Python 2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Queue'

/home/myuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py:1147: ResourceWarning: Implicitly cleaning up <TemporaryDirectory '/tmp/pipenv-cLTIqh-requirements'>
  warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)
```

Why `Python 2.7`? Let's check the python version used in the virtualenv:

```
» pipenv shell
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
. /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/svc-J_VF07t3/bin/activate
» . /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/svc-J_VF07t3/bin/activate
» python --version
Python 3.6.4
```

Correct! What about `pipenv` itself:

```
» which pipenv
/home/myuser/.local/bin/pipenv
```

So it seems that the problem is that, although my `virtualenv` is using `Python 3`, `pipenv` itself is using `Python 2` (the system Python). `pipenv` has been installed as [recommended](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv), using the system-wide python interpreter:

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

And it is indeed installed, and found:

```
» which pipenv
/home/myuser/.local/bin/pipenv

» pipenv --version
pipenv, version 11.1.3
```

It would not make any sense to be forced to reinstall `pipenv` according to the python interpreter that my project is going to use.

Why is `pipenv` using the system python when installing packages in a virtualenv, instead of using that virtualenv's python? How can I decouple the python interpreter used by `pipenv` and the python interpreter used by my project?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. It started happening when fiddling with pipenv and a new minor version of python 3. As unhelpful as this may sound, the solution was to open a new shell (not sourcing the shell) and invoking pipenv shell worked as did my `python manage.py` command.

fwiw my error was complaining about python 2.7 throughout on string interpolation `'%d' % foo`, but this works in python 3.